# Old Photos synced to icloud

Tags: icloud, iphone, photos, streaming

I am trying to clean up my Iphone 4S and moving photos to icloud. I tried to create a photo stream but I do not have the option on this phone. any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Photo Stream is gone since iOS 8.
Even though your 4S will be on an older OS, Photo Stream is not the way to securely save your photos, as Apple are starting to limit to the last 30 days only.

I'd suggest Dropbox or similar, or get them onto your computer with iPhoto [Mac] or Photo Gallery - part of Windows Essentials [PC]